# Length of an ellipse

Tags: integration, arc-length

I am asked to give the length of the curve:

$\gamma: [0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^2$, $\gamma(t)=(a\cos(t), b\sin(t))$ where $a,b\in(0,\infty)$

We get to solving the following:

$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2\sin(t)^2+b^2\cos(t)^2}\, dt$

Which should not be possible to integrate probably.

For $a=b$ I can solve it, but thats it. We would get:

$2\pi\cdot a$

Is there any way, which does not involve using the form above and its solution with "second kind elliptic integrals" which wolframalpha refers to?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot avoid elliptic integrals but there are very good approximations.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks. I wonder because in the lecture notes I study, there are no such approximations or even anything about elliptic curves. I think that this homework was a "mistake". Or not well choosen.

Comment: About the perimeter of the ellipse, have a look at pages 138+ of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view). I still have to mention Ramanujan's approximation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference), the circumference $C$ of an ellipse is given by
$$C = 4 a\, E(e)\qquad \text{with} \qquad e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$$
The exact infinite series is given by
$$C=2\pi a \left[1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\right)^2 \frac{e^{2n}}{2n-1}\right]$$ but a much faster convergen series is 
$$C = \pi (a+b) \left[1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n(2n-1) n!}\right)^2 {h^n}\right]\qquad \text{with} \qquad h= \frac {(a-b)^2 } {(a+b)^2}$$

In the linked page, you will find a series of approximations wich can be more than sufficient for practical usage.

Comment: (+1) A practical approximations for a small eccentricity is given by $$ C\approx 2\pi\left(\frac{a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}}{2}\right)^{2/3}. $$